# what fuction fits for unbalanced parantheses

Tags: c, function

Input

```
s = "()())()"
```

Output:

```
1
```

Here in the below code I should fill code to count unbalanced perantheses
Tried to start with counting first but gave me wrong output

```
#include <stdio.h>

int invalid_parentheses_count(char parentheses[])
{
  // write your code here
  int i,count=0;
  for (i=0;i<=strlen(parentheses);i++)
  {
    if(parentheses[i]=='('|| parentheses[i]==')')
    count = count+parentheses[i];
  }
  printf("%d",count);
  return 0;
}
```

For example, given the string "()())()", you should return 1. Given the string ")(", you should return 2, since we must remove all of them.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: `count+parentheses[i];` ? You are adding a parenthesis to integer?

Comment: yes i tried to count the number of perentheses but that gave me some value

Comment: increment a temporary counter on `(` and decrement it on `)`.  When it becomes `<0`, increment the result counter and reset the temporary counter to `0`.  At end, add the temporary counter to the result counter